# How to fetch the current session's utm parameters in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say a user gets to one of my pages with all the utm data (utm_campaign, etc.). On the page they land, a session is created in Google Analytics with all this info.

Then, they browse my site and get to another page. On that page, the utm_campaign isn't in the query string anymore.

Is there a way I can fetch the utm_campaign data?

Please note I use Universal Analytics, so it's ga instead of _gaq.

**UPDATE:** In case anyone is wondering, this code doesn't work:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
 alert(tracker.get('campaignName'));
 alert(tracker.get('campaignSource'));
 alert(tracker.get('campaignMedium'));
 alert(tracker.get('campaignKeyword'));
 alert(tracker.get('campaignContent'));
 alert(tracker.get('campaignId'));
});
```